# Adding content to a linear layout choosing it's position

Tags: java, android, android-studio, layout

I am building my first android app, it's something simple.
You can fill in some data, this data is sent to an other activity and on the new activity you can confirm the data and the data will be stored in a local file on the device. That's the plan.

Now when I send the data from my mainactivity to my second activity it get's added at the bottom of the layout. I have a button in that activity I want the data to be displayed above the button not under it. How can achieve this?

This is the way I get my data from the previous activity and how I display it

```
//get data
Intent intent = getIntent();
String firstname = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.FIRSTNAME);
String lastname = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.LASTNAME);
//make texrview to displat the data
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText("Hey " + firstname + " " + lastname + "!");
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
layout.addView(textView);
```

Here's my xml of my content view(mysecondactivty)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
     tools:showIn="@layout/activity_display_form"
     android:id="@+id/content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_confirmForm" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Create an empty text field above the button.  Populate it with the data from the other activity.  No need to try to create it at runtime.

Comment: I'm pretty new at android development, how do I populate it with data from the other activity?

Comment: addView(View view, int position, LayoutParams params)

Comment: layout.addView(textView,0,new LinearLayout.Layoutparams(Layoutparams.MATCH_PARENT,Layoutparams.WRAP_CONTENT) );

Answer (score 0):

you can use addView (View child, int index) to insert your TextView at the position you want